# absolute database batch move

Tags: delphi

I would like to use the batch component to archive some old records within a table. I looked at the example on the Ace components site but I am unsure how to use it. The command is :

```
DestinationTable.BatchMove(SourceTable,TABSBatchMoveType(bmtAppend));
```

For the task I intended to use two datetimepickers. So a query would go something like with parameters:

```
SELECT * from MYTABLE where DATE BETWEEN :a1 and :a2
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a1').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a2').AsDate := DateTimePicker2.Date;
ABSQuery.ExecSql;
```

How do I incorporate the query with the batchmove command? I want all the retrieved records to move from my source table to destination table.

Comment: why is this tagged with so many Delphi versions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolute Database's `BatchMove` appears to be modeled after the old BDE `TBatchMove`, which required two `TTable` components; IIRC, it didn't work with `TQuery`, but I could be remembering wrong. (The BDE has been deprecated for more than a decade, and I haven't used it since Delphi 1.)

You don't need `BatchMove`, though. You can do it all with your single query (exception handling omitted for brevity):

```
// Copy rows into destination
ABSTQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO DestTable'#32 +
  '(SELECT * from MYTABLE where DATE BETWEEN :a1 and :a2)';
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a1').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a2').AsDate := DateTimePicker2.Date;
ABSTQuery1.ExecSql; 
ABSTQuery1.Close;

// Remove them from source (you said "move", after all)
ABSTQuery1.SQL.Text := 'DELETE FROM MyTable'#32 +
  `WHERE Date BETWEEN :a1 and :a2';
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a1').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a2').AsDate := DateTimePicker2.Date;
ABSTQuery1.ExecSql; 
ABSTQuery1.Close;
```

Replace `DestTable` with the name of the destination table in the first SQL statement.

More info in the Absolute Database [on-line manual](http://www.componentace.com/help/absdb_manual/insertstatement.htm)

I haven't used Absolute Database, but if their SQL support includes scripting (I'll leave that research up to you - docs link above) and multiple statements, you can do it in one pass:

```
// Note addition of `;` at end of each SQL statement
// and change in param names for second statement.
// Some DBs will allow you to just use one pair, and
// set the value for each once. Some require setting
// each twice, and some require unique param names.
// Check the documentation for Absolute DB.
//
ABSTQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO DestTable'#32 +
  '(SELECT * from MYTABLE where DATE BETWEEN :a1 and :a2);'
  'DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE Date BETWEEN :d1 and :d2;';
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a1').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('a2').AsDate := DateTimePicker2.Date;

// New param names for second pass
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('d1').AsDate := DateTimePicker1.Date;
ABSTQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName ('d2').AsDate := DateTimePicker2.Date;
ABSTQuery1.ExecSQL;
ABSTQuery1.Close;
```

Comment: Sorry. It's a space character. It's easier to use that than to put a space in; the space is too easy to miss at the end of the string, and if you leave it out it's a syntax error. `#32` is a space, `#9` is a tab, `#13` is a carriage return (CR), and `#10` is a line feed; they're commonly used characters (another one you might find useful is `#34`, which is a double-quote). `#13#10`, for instance, are the end-of-line characters for Windows systems, and they're at the end of every line of source in the IDE code editor. You can look at any ASCII chart; the `#` means `character`.