# Replacement for batchMove in ADO Delphi XE

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

I am Migrating all applcations from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE . I am replacing BDE component with ADO and I dont have any replacement for TbatchMove in ADO. Can you please provide some solution for TbatchMove replacement. I am using Sql Server 2008 Database as backend.

We are migrating data from files(schema and text). Text file contains all the data.So in existing component Tbatchmove, source is Folder path (where schema and text files are kept ) and destination is Sql database. So I am not able to figure out how to do this using ADO and assign folder path so that that will directly update my database

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10906274/62576) might help. It's based on Absolute Database, but the information is the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct analagous component to TBatchMove in ADO. If you are moving data from one table into another you can do something like this :-

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TABLETWO
SELECT col1, col2
FROM dbo.TABLEONE
```

Comment: We are migrating data from files(schema and text). Text file contains all the data.So in existing component Tbatchmove, source is Folder path (where schema and text files are kept ) and destination is Sql database. So I am not able to figure out how to do this using ADO and assign folder path so that that will directly update my database.